# Getting a "SIGSEGV" segmentation fault and unsure why

Tags: c++, set, binary-search-tree, nodes

My program requires me to create a binary search tree that is also a set. I've got up to inserting items into it and having that work correctly, but my issue comes when I'm attempting to get recursively get the size of the tree, aka how many nodes there are. Below is all the code that matters I believe.

```
struct SetNode
{
    T data;
    SetNode<T>* left;
    SetNode<T>* right;

    SetNode(const T& value);
};


//Set based on a BST
template <class T>
class MySet
{
private:
    SetNode<T>* root;

public:

    //constructor, insert function, "contains" function declared here

    //get number of items contained
    int size() const;

    int sizeHelper(SetNode<T>* curNode) const;
}

template<typename T>
int MySet<T>::size() const {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return 0;
    else
        return this->sizeHelper(root);
}

template<typename T>
int MySet<T>::sizeHelper(SetNode<T>* curNode) const {
    return 1 + sizeHelper(curNode->left) + sizeHelper(curNode->right);
}
```

The issue arises in `main` after I declare `Set<string> setA` and attempt to call `size` with `setA.size()`. From the debugger, I've seen that this causes the aforementioned SIGSEGV error. I can change the declaration of `sizeHelper` and even remove it if need be, but other than the code within it, `size` must remain as it is. Should `sizeHelper` be a non-member function? Removing the const doesn't work.

Comment: Your belief that this is "all the code that matters" is incorrect. The declaration of `sizeHelper` has absolutely nothing to do with anything. You have a bug somewhere which results in undefined behavior, a.k.a. crash. There is nothing in the shown code that, by itself, will cause a segfault, therefore the problem must be in code that's not shown. You need to show something that meets all requirements of a [mre], as explained in the [help]. See [ask] for more information. P.S. if you don't know what the problem is, adding or removing keywords is unlikely to help. You need to figure it out.

Comment: What did your debugger say about the crash?

Answer (score 2):

Your `sizeHelper` is a recursive function with no exit condition, you just keep reading the `left` and `right` fields from the node you're given, but you never check if they are `nullptr`. If you do pass `nullptr`, you have UB and possibly a segfault.

To avoid it you need to add an exit condition like so.

```cpp
template<typename T>
int MySet<T>::sizeHelper(SetNode<T>* curNode) const {
    if (curNode == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + sizeHelper(curNode->left) + sizeHelper(curNode->right);
}
```

Comment: Note that doing this means you no longer need the `nullptr` check in `size`.